# Intent From Class Not Launching

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to launch an intent from an activity class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, (Obscured)MapActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("stop", stop);
    this.startActivity(i);
```

And here is my intent receiver in (Obscured)MapActivity:

```
Intent i = this.getIntent();
if (i != null && i.getSerializableExtra("stop") != null) {
        this.displayLocations();
        BusStop tempStop = new BusStop();
        tempStop = (BusStop) i.getSerializableExtra("stop");
        this.goToStop(tempStop);
    }
```

But for some reason it isn't launching. I have another case right above that:

```
if (i != null && i.getSerializableExtra("loc") != null) {
        this.displayLocations();
        this.goToLocation((Location) i.getSerializableExtra("loc"));
    }
```

That works just fine, and the intent launcher code is almost completely identical. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm also using SherlockListActivity, not sure if that changes anything.

```
<activity
        android:name=".(Obscured)MapActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout"
```

I'm happy to provide more info, this has been bugging me for a few hours now.

ANSWER:
Found the issue. For some reason when I add the extras (stop) which is serializable, it breaks. Commenting out the putExtra() and it works. The problem was trying to serialize a GeoPoint.

Comment: Do you include the Google Maps MapActivity in your app?  If so your app might be trying to reference that activity instead of your custom MapActivity.

Comment: It's called something other than MapActivity, sorry, had to obscure that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. For some reason when I add the extras (stop) which is serializable, it breaks. Commenting out the setExtra() and it works. Not sure why it won't pass it though, the class extends serializable but everything I try just makes it break again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MapActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Comment: Can anyone please help? I cannot for the life of me figure out why MapActivity is not getting the intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that helps, but the [JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) of `putExtra()` state that you **must** have a package prefix in the name of the extra:

> The name must include a package prefix, for example the app
>   com.android.contacts would use names like
>   "com.android.contacts.ShowAll"